# How do I calculate the zigzag indicator?

Tags: indicator

Zigzag indicator as defined here: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/z/zig_zag_indicator.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing 'zigzag indicator' into google yields Investopedia's entry as first search result. Importantly it states:

> To use the zig zag indicator, a percentage of price movements must be set. Although the default value for a zig zag is 5%, a setting of 9% would ensure that only price fluctuations of 9% or more would be shown in the chart. This eliminates smaller price swings and allows the analyst to see the bigger picture. Normally, closing prices of securities are used, and imaginary points are placed on the given chart where the price reverses by the set percentages. These points are then connected by straight lines and the required information appears.

I have never calculated one but to me these look like simpler versions of point-and-figure reversals. The steps seem to be:

1) Take a historical set of close prices and set your reversal parameter, e.g. 9%.

2) Consider the first point $x_0$. Find the first subsequent point that differs from $x_0$ by 9%, which establishes either an up or downtrend, set this point as $x_1$.

3) If the price continues in the same trend update the point $x_1$ to a new high/low.

4) The first subsequent point that reverses the trend by 9% from $x_1$ is set to $x_2$.

5) repeat 3) and 4) determining new points.

Note that the final points of the chart are in an undetermined trend since information either about a new high/low or a reversal is needed to categorise them.